# Multiple databases or multiple row tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a question about how big companies manage a database structure, let's say if i have an ecommerce app something like shopify which is the best approach you take:

a) When a new user creates an account a new database with his tables is created specifically for that user (i think if for some reason this database fail the other databases of other users remain working)?

b) When a new user creates an account Instead of create a new database, the app just create a new row in a table for his login and then all the products of all users are in the same table and only the user_id is the difference between one product of a store and another.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Option `a` is a *horrible* idea. That's the sort of stuff you see on [the Daily WTF](http://www.thedailywtf.com/).

Comment: The fact that you are actually considering (a).... means you should study a lot more about good database design before starting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you should go for the second option (b), for alot of reasons:
1. Most of the data in your database shall be accessible for all users, so you don't want to have the same data stored in multiple places.
2. Sooner or later, you will come up with features where you want to share or link data between different users, etc. 
3. Your first choice (a) would be extremely resource consuming compared to the second choice (b).
4. Well, the list can go on and on... :)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the second choice - much more efficient and smarter.

Think about the number of the users, let's say 10k for example. 
you realy don't want to handle this mass of tables!

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Option B. This will reduce your work load and help in reporting needs down the road. Just make sure you use a robust database design to handle load when writing to database tables.